# Access Personal OneDrive API with client_credentials

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

For a project, I need to display some files stored on a Personal OneDrive.

I can't use a classic OAuth2 authentication, I need to be authenticate as an application and not as an user, like explained on this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

But adminConsent seems to be only for entreprise subscriptions.
Is there any way to do that with a Personal OneDrive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a solution with *Code Flow authentication* and *offline_access scope*. 
With that method, an admin have to connect one time to get a refresh token which can be uses after to get an access_token at any time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#code-flow

Answer (score 0):

I try in vain to declare a sharepoint application in my personal OneDrive, but it seems to be enterprise feature.

Have you try to generate a link to embed your folder ? You can do that with the  Icon on the navigation menu when you select a OneDrive folder.

I can't see any solution to share your file by declaring an application, I guess this is restricted in Personal OneDrive. I did give it a try in enterprise One Drive and it seems I can declare an app using the maginc link

```
/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
```

Hope you will find a solution

Comment: the icon looks like "</>"

Comment: Indeed, I can embed any folder. Thx btw, I didn't know that feature... But I want a personal and transparent integration of these files on my website. And I don't want people to be redirected on OneDrive interface...

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution which doesn't seem to be the same as yours but may be helpful. If you follow the docs about creating a daemon application, you can create an access token given you have the following:

- your client ID
- your client secret
- your tenant name

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview) for info on daemon applications. There are examples also on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=java) for how to actually make the request.  From that page, this is the HTTP request body.

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1           //Line breaks for clarity.
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

You will get back a response like the following. You can then use the `access_token` to make API requests.

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "ACCESS_TOKEN"
}
```

You can find a Python code [example here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/tree/master/1-Call-MsGraph-WithSecret).